# iText7 How do I know Table flows to next page like ITextshap Column.HasMoretext?

Tags: itext, itext7

I have a form where I have to place some fixed data on top and bottom with a variable table in between. If table does not fit on first page, there should be created more pages as needed to acomodate Table.
But for page 2, 3, 4... I still have to print top & bottom, but this time a short version of whats was placed on page 1.
In ItextSharp5 with ColumnText.HasMoreText = true, I know when a new page is needed and can make a new page with proper top & bottom data before drop remaining table.

So how can I achieve same behaviour with iText7?
I did not found a way to know when a table needs some more room

Answer (score 1):

After some reading, found a starting point at [Chapter 2: Adding content to a Canvas or a Document](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-adding-content-canvas-or-document)

on 3th block of code.